# What is the most efficient way to get 110 V from 220 V single-phase wiring?

Tags: electrical

Here in Chile, we have 220 V 50 Hz *single phase* coming from the electrical grid in most residential houses. Due to my buying habits, I have some devices that have been imported from 100-120 V  countries. For example, I have a Japanese PS1 that runs at 100 V/50-60 Hz and subwoofer from Amazon that runs at 110 V/50-60 Hz and a bunch of others.

What would be the most efficient way to get ~110 V 50 Hz?

The reason why I want something efficient is because all of the devices are on the same area (subwoofer is under my desk, PS1 is to the left of my desk under my TV, etc.) and I don't want to have one step down transformer per device.

Comment: Most electronics these days (and I accept that PS1 is old) don't really care what the input voltage or frequency is - they just feed it into a switched mode power supply and everything is happy.  This saves the manufacturer a lot of money as they can sell the same device in Europe/US/etc with just a plug change.  Of course, you need to inspect the device carefully, as putting 220V into a device which only accepts 110V will not end well.

Comment: The thing is, I have inspected the devices and they only work in the 100-110-120v range. The PS1 blows up with 220v (don't ask how I know this lol) and the Subwoofer uses a transformer so it requires the 110v to be able to step down from 110v to whatever it needs.

Comment: You might consider altering your buying habits slightly to ensure that the products you purchase in the future either A) support 220v 50Hz natively, or B) have switching power supplies that support "world voltages" as noted above by Martin. You might be getting the cheapest device Amazon sells in the category, but when you add in the cost of a transformer (upgrade for more devices), is it really that cheap?

Comment: @Lemon the PS1 was sold in lots of countries and I bet they made the PS1 the same but made the power supply brick different. You might check whether you can buy a PS1 power supply brick made for your country. Maybe someone is even still making new ones.

Comment: PS1 uses a line input to an internal power supply. However you could swap out the power supply module with one from a 240v country.

Comment: The *obvious* way is a single transformer large enough to support all your devices. 
 If you have a powerful subwoofer you'll need a large transformer.   Why do you think the obvious way is not the most efficient?

Comment: @FreeMan I keep my habits like that! Is just that certain devices (specifically retro consoles!) can only be obtained from ~110v countries (for example, if I want an NTSC Fat PS2 I would need to get a 100v or 110v model).

Comment: @KMJ I did my research about the PS1 PSU and I found a lot of different modifications for the power supply from swapping the internal PSU to switching to an external power brick and even USB-C Power Delivery. I might look around and mod one of the two models I have, but I also want to keep the other one stock.

Comment: Not at all sure if the transformers I use for power tools will produce noise, but, in U.K. we use quite heavy yellow boxes on building sites, to step power down to 110v. For safety reasons. There certainly would be enough power in one of those to run all and more of your pieces of equipment. They step from 220>110v, and run all the heavy tools (breakers, etc.) on site.

Comment: @Tim - don't they have an earthed centre tap on the secondary winding, so the max shock to earth would be 55v? Not sure how that might affect things in a house (RCDs etc).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I've used them for many decades, plugged into domestic 220v supplies with RCDs and never found problems.

Comment: A good option, https://lvyuan.co/ makes up/down converters. The transformer in the device works at tens kHz, so it can be cheaper and lighter; like that in a PC power supply.They handle highly inductive load and have a decent PFC. The highest-rated unit VTUS-5000VA is enough to provide 3300W with plenty of surge headroom, and sells for $160 ATM. Do get the highest-rated one, the extra $40 well spent. You'll need a good brand 15A rated cord (14AWG for 1m, 12AWG 2m); units shipped from the US come with the US NEMA 5-15 plugs. The cord connector is the standard hi-temp 15A IEC C16.

Comment: Ah, and use the 16A (large) type L outlet only. You likely have universal outlets accepting all 3 plugs (C and large/small L) if you're living in a newer construction, so it's usually the matter of power cord choice. But if not, have a large L outlet installed.

Answer (score 11):

A *step-down [**auto**-transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer)* is appropriate for loads like this.  They only use one winding instead of 2 in many transformer designs, saving wiring (cost and weight).  The isolating transformers used for power tools necessarily use 2 coils.

These are often sold just as "voltage converters" or "transformers" and you need to get one rated for the total load you'll be using at once.  500W is easily available, for example.  Some of the bigger ones do both step-up and step-down - be sure to set it up correctly.

Answer (score 7):

A transformer.

There are yellow transformers that are designed to power professional devices in the UK from the grid (230V)

I have one and it works a treat.
But if you order it then postage may be costly as they are very heavy.

This is a link to a similar product to the one I have and supports the drills etc I use: https://www.screwfix.com/p/defender-3000va-intermittent-transformer-distribution-kit-240v-110v/230kp#_=p

Comment: And make sure the transformer can support the powerdraw of the device.

Comment: note this is kind of a "brute force solution" because it always works, but it's expensive and bulky. Actually I clicked the link and saw it was $90 which is not bad. I thought it would be more like $400

Comment: @user253751 I mentioned that it would be costly to post.

Comment: Also note that any UK 'building site' 110v transformer, whist being absolutely great for the job will also have 'building site' sockets, not standard UK 13A sockets. They're always yellow for 110v - https://www.tester.co.uk/tools-and-accessories/110v-site-construction-equipment/110v-sockets-plugs-couplers

Comment: @Tetsujin - that's true - they're similar to the big round blue plug/sockets found on campsites - but there are plenty of ways to re-wire with other plug/sockets - as long as they don't fit 220v stuff.

Comment: @Tim - very similar, yes, but they're keyed so you can't fit a yellow 120v one in a blue 240v socket. It's a subset of [IEC 60309](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60309). You'll still need to buy one to get you started, no matter what you connect to the other end.

Comment: @Tetsujin - true, they're keyed, although I've swapped round before now, as the pins are identical. Luckily, I'm not colour-blind... (and I know what I'm doing!) Of course you'll need to buy a male to start the chain, but if you're buying the transformer, it's a good bet the shop will be happy to sell you a plug, or even a lead with male/female.

Comment: @user253751: Note the duty cycle 5 min on/15 min off in the spec. This is why it's so cheap.

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient way of solving your XY-type problem is to get proper power supplies for these appliances.

It may be even simpler if the original power supply units are in fact 100-240V compatible and you could need only a plug adapter, but this is not always the case.

---

What's wrong with transformers:

1. Bulky
2. High quality ones are expensive, usually more than the 220V power supplies for your gear.
3. Low quality ones are a real fire risk even with no load. Some of them are noisy as well.
4. They have their own power draw (e.g. a 100W transformer will draw 1-3W even without load. I don't know how much the electricity costs in Chile, but small expenses tend to add up.
5. Did you say subwoofer? Be prepared to get some audible mains hum.
6. Even high quality ones are hard to get right in regard to grounding. This comes with some risks.

Comment: Proper power supplies aren't always available, especially once you get into the higher wattage ranges.

Comment: @Mark really? We talk about electronics. Toasters and vacuum cleaners are different. For even higher wattages (e.g. a kitchen range) 230V gets the default option even in the US.

Comment: Point 5 makes no sense. Any AC voltage is transformed so many times from the generating plant to your outlet than throwing a couple more in between changes nothing at all. Also, never heard of a receiver or sub with a replaceable power supply... The source of noise in home-grade audio gear is mainly cheap design, sensitive to ground loops from improper connections, and signal ground is always isolated from the mains, obviously, for safety. The only thing I'd do is overrate the transformer for audio power amps by 10-15%, unless I had a reason to trust their stated power rating.